# How to add a DocumentColorizingTransformer to AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdevelop, avalonedit

I've implemented my own DocumentColorizingTransformer. But now, how do I add it to the AvalonEdit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add it to the `textEditor.TextArea.TextView.LineTransformers` collection.