# AvalonEdit: Highlight based on non-regex rules

Tags: c#, avalonedit

Is it possible to highlight text in AvalonEdit based on non-regex rules?

Motivation: I have custom lang with different kind of members and want to show each of them with unique color, but regex doesn't allow that.

*actual language is different, C# is used only for demonstration purposes*

```cs
class MyClass
{
    public void Func() { }
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

With regex-based highlight I can't show whether this token is method or property

```cs
nameof(MyClass.Func); // yellow highlight
nameof(MyClass.Prop); // blue highlight
```

One of solutions is to use `IBackgroundRenderer` but it will highlight only background, not foreground

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478403/how-to-add-a-documentcolorizingtransformer-to-avalonedit

Comment: @JimFoye that looks like the thing I was looking for. Thanks!